# How to change the url based on a Drop Down List?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am using a Drop Down List for selecting some options.  Everything works fine, all I need is to change the name in the URL.  Is there a way to change the URL ONLY based on the option?

Default Puma -

```
Default.aspx?Dept=Shoes&Type=Puma
```

if Nike is selected -

```
Default.aspx?Dept=Shoes&Type=Nike
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle this on the server you could enable the autopostback property of the control and create a SelectedIndexChanged event to call a method to identify the selected option and redirect based on this selection.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("Default.aspx?Dept=Shoes&Type={0}", this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue), true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

More specifically

```
<select onchange="window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value="#">--  Select a Search Engine ---</option>
  <option value="http://www.live.com">Live Search</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to do this with Javascript.  You can change `window.location` from Javascript and it will redirect you to whatever you changed it to.

Here is an unobtrusive way of doing it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="dd">
            <option value="http://example.com/first">first</option>
            <option value="http://example.com/second">second</option>
        </select>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (dd = document.getElementById("dd")) {   
                dd.onchange = function() {
                    window.location = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```